# http xml response is not parsable while creating order

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I have written a web service for order creation as below

```
<?php
    @ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    define('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_', true);

    require_once('db.php');
    require_once('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');


  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 

    $customerId = $_POST['customerid'];   

    $address = $_POST['address']; 
    $phoneno = $_POST['phoneno']; 
    $city = $_POST['city']; 
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $totalprice = $_POST['totalprice']; 
    $orders = $_POST['orders'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'] ;
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'] ;
    $paymethod = "cod"; // cod or payu// cod or payu



    $curdate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  
    if($paymethod == "payu") {
        $orderModule = "citruspayu" ;
        $orderPayment = "PayUmoney " ;
    } else if($paymethod =="cod") {
        $orderModule = "ps_cashondelivery" ;
        $orderPayment = "Cash on delivery (cod)" ;
     }   

      $curdate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');   
    $orders = str_replace("\\", "",$orders);  
       $orders = json_decode($orders, true) ;
       $ocnt=sizeof($orders); 
       //print_r($ocnt);

        // need to check with product id and qunatity - ps_stock_available
    // for ($i = 0 ; $i < $ocnt ; $i++) {
    //  $proid=  $orders[$i]['product_id'];
    //  $quan=$orders[$i]['total_qty']; 
    // }    
        $result = array() ; 
       // print_r($result);
    try
    {
        $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `ps_customer` WHERE id_customer='".$customerId."'"); 

        $cnt=mysqli_affected_rows($con);    

        if($cnt!=0) { //to place order      
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);  
            $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
            $xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/addresses?ws_key='.PS_WS_AUTH_KEY.'&schema=synopsis'));
            $resources = $xml->children()->children();  
            $resources->id_country = 110; //India  
            $resources->id_state = 348; //Tamil Nadu 
            $resources->id_customer = $customerId;
            $resources->alias = "My address";
            $resources->lastname = $lastname ;  //$row['lastname'];// last name is required   
            $resources->firstname = $firstname;

            $resources->address1 = $address;
            $resources->postcode = $postcode;


            $resources->city = $city;          
            $resources->phone_mobile = $phoneno;
            $resources->active = 1;
            $resources->date_add = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


            $resources->date_upd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $sql = mysqli_query($con,"select * from ps_address where id_customer=$customerId and firstname='".$firstname."' and lastname='".$lastname."' and address1='".$address."' and city='".$city."' and postcode='".$postcode."' and (phone_mobile= $phoneno or phone=$phoneno)");
            //$sqll= "select * from ps_address where id_customer=$customerId and firstname='".$firstname."' and lastname='".$lastname."' and address1='".$address."' and city='".$city."' and postcode='".$postcode."' and (phone_mobile= $phoneno or phone=$phoneno)";
         //  echo $sqll;
            $cnt=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
         //  echo "addrs count....".($cnt);
            if($cnt == 0) {             
                $opt = array('resource' => 'addresses?ws_key='.PS_WS_AUTH_KEY.'&schema=synopsis');
               //   echo "111";
                $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();// echo $opt['postXml'];
              //    echo "222";
                $xml = $webService->add($opt);  
               // echo "333";
                $addressid = $xml->address->id;
               // echo "string".$addressid;
            }
            else {
                $address=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql) ;
                $addressid =  $address['id_address'] ;
                //echo "address id---".$addressid ;
            }
             //echo "now";
            //exit();

            if($addressid) {  // if addressid exists
                // to insert cart details          
                $cxml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/carts?ws_key='.PS_WS_AUTH_KEY.'&schema=synopsis'));
                $cresources = $cxml->children()->children();
                $cresources->id_carrier = 4;
                $cresources->id_shop_group = 1;
                $cresources->id_shop = 1;
                $cresources->delivery_option = 'a:1:{i:'.$addressid.';s:2:"4,";}';
                $cresources->id_customer = $customerId;

                $cresources->id_lang = 2;
                $cresources->id_address_delivery =$addressid;
                $cresources->id_address_invoice = $addressid;
                $cresources->id_currency = 1;          
                $cresources->id_guest = 1;  
                $cresources->date_add = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $cresources->date_upd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
                $opt = array('resource' => 'carts?ws_key='.PS_WS_AUTH_KEY.'&schema=synopsis');
                $opt['postXml'] = $cxml->asXML(); 
                $cxml = $webService->add($opt);             
                $cartid = $cxml->cart->id;   
                echo "cart id===".$cartid ;
                if($cxml) {
                    /*insert cart product*/
                    $delqur = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM ps_cart_product WHERE id_cart = $cartid;");        
                    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $ocnt ; $i++) {
                        $proid=  $orders[$i]['product_id'];

                        $quan=$orders[$i]['total_qty'];                     
                        $qur = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ps_cart_product (`id_cart`,`id_product`,`id_address_delivery`,`id_shop`,
                            `id_product_attribute`,`quantity`,`date_add`) VALUES('$cartid','$proid','$addressid','1','0','$quan','$curdate');");    

                    } 
                    /*insert cart product*/ 
                    /*to insert order details*/
                    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG); 
                    $orderxml =  $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/orders?ws_key='.PS_WS_AUTH_KEY.'&schema=synopsis'));
                    $orderxml->order->id_address_delivery = $addressid;                  
                    $orderxml->order->id_address_invoice  = $addressid;                  
                    $orderxml->order->id_cart = $cartid;                     
                    $orderxml->order->id_currency = 1;                   
                    $orderxml->order->id_lang = 2;                   
                    $orderxml->order->id_customer = $customerId;                     
                    $orderxml->order->id_carrier = 4; // Check your id_carrier                   
                    $orderxml->order->current_state = 3;                     
                    $orderxml->order->module = $orderModule ; 
                    //'citruspayu' ; //'ps_cashondelivery';                  
                    $orderxml->order->valid = 0;                     
                    $orderxml->order->id_shop_group = 1;                     
                    $xml->order->id_shop = 1;                    
                    $orderxml->order->payment = $orderPayment ; 
                    //"PayUmoney" ; //'Cash on delivery (COD)';                  
                    $orderxml->order->total_discounts = 0;                   
                    $orderxml->order->total_discounts_tax_incl =0;                   
                    $orderxml->order->total_discounts_tax_excl =0;                   
                    $orderxml->order->total_paid = $totalprice;                  
                    $orderxml->order->total_paid_tax_incl = $totalprice;                     
                    $orderxml->order->total_paid_tax_excl = $totalprice;                     
                    $orderxml->order->total_paid_real = $totalprice;                     
                    $orderxml->order->total_products = 2 ;                   
                    $orderxml->order->total_products_wt = 200 ;                  
                    $orderxml->order->total_shipping = 0;                    
                    $orderxml->order->total_shipping_tax_incl = 0;                   
                    $orderxml->order->total_shipping_tax_excl = 0;                   
                    $orderxml->order->conversion_rate = 1;
                //  $orderxml->order->from_device="app" ;
                    $orderxml->order->secure_key = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));; 
                    $opt = array('resource' => 'orders?sendemail=1'); 
                    $orderxml = $orderxml->asXML();
                    $opt['postXml'] = $orderxml ; //echo $opt['postXml'];
                    $orderxml = $webService->add($opt);                 
                    $orderid=$orderxml->order->id;                      
                    if($orderxml) {
                        $findSecLastInvoice=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `ps_order_invoice` ORDER BY `delivery_number` DESC LIMIT 1"); 
                        $icnt=mysqli_affected_rows($con);
                        if($icnt!=0) {
                            $inrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($findSecLastInvoice); 
                            $dnumber =$inrow['delivery_number'] + 1;
                        } else {
                            $dnumber =1;
                        }
                        $findOrderid=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `ps_orders` WHERE id_cart='$cartid'"); 
                        $orderrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($findOrderid);                         
                        $update_orderinvoice = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ps_order_invoice SET delivery_number='$dnumber',delivery_date='$curdate' WHERE id_order='".$orderrow['id_order']."'") ;
                        if($update_orderinvoice) {
                            $update_order = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ps_orders SET delivery_number='$dnumber',delivery_date='$curdate' WHERE id_order='".$orderrow['id_order']."'") ;
                            $update_orderhistory = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ps_order_history WHERE id_order='".$orderrow['id_order']."'") ;
                            $result['status']= "Success";   
                            $result['orderid'] = strval($orderid) ;
                        }   
                    } else {
                        $result['status']= "Error";
                    } //$oxml
                } //$cxml

                // to insert cart details   
            }  //$address id
        } 
        else { //not exists
            $result['status']="Account Not Found";
        }

    //   header('Content-type: application/json');

       echo json_encode($result);
       mysqli_close($con);
    }
    catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e)
    {
        // Here we are dealing with errors
        $trace = $e->getTrace();
        if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
        else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
        else echo 'Other error<br />'.$e->getMessage();
    }       
                }//post     
             else {
                     echo "No Post Parameters" ;
                } 
                     //}            
                 ?>
```

While running in postman I get a success message. but when I see app log am getting an error as HTTP XML response is not parsable and LibXMLError::__set_state error...somebody pls help. I have also trimmed it but no use.1

I'm using PSWebServiceLibrary.php for Prestashop and in the add function, this is the code which sends the XML request for parsing.